# Build excluding test modules

Tags: go, dependency-management, go-build

My project has the following structure:

```
├── api
│   ├── api.go
│   ├── api_test.go
│   ├── other_files...
├── cmd
│   └── main.go
```

Under cmd/main.go I have the entrypoint of my Go project.

Since I am also creating some test files, I have other classes used for test purposes.

My go.mod is like:

```
require (
    github.com/gorilla/mux v1.8.0
    github.com/stretchr/testify v1.6.1          <-used for test
    gotest.tools v2.2.0+incompatible            <-used for test 
    k8s.io/api v0.19.0
    k8s.io/apimachinery v0.19.0
    k8s.io/client-go v0.19.0
)
```

My doubt is related to the build phase:
When doing `go build ./cmd/main.go`, am I selecting only the correct modules used from `main.go` and all its references across the code, excluding the unused modules listed in `go.mod` used for test classes?

Is there any `ldd` command to be sure I am linking only the required modules?
I assume that Go is optimized to do that, but I would like to be sure about that.

Comment: "When doing go build ./cmd/main.go" then you are doing it 100% wrong. Supply packages to `go build`. For the rest of your question: There is nothing to worry. Just forget about  "test modules" or "test dependencies". This is a no-issue.

Comment: Note that `ldd` is the dynamic linker. It is not going to load anything more than what's required. When you link at compile time, you use `ld`. The linker only links what's necessary by default. You really have to force it to get additional things that are not required.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

When go builds a package normally (`go build` or `go install`) it will ignore any files with the name pattern `*_test.go`. This means that object code for any packages that are only imported from those test files will not be linked into your executable.

So if you're just careful not to import the test packages from your non-test code you're good.

If you're not sure, you can check the "build list" by running:

```sh
go list -m all
```

From the root of your module. This will list the set of modules providing packages for the build.

Ref: [go - The main module and the build list](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-The_main_module_and_the_build_list)

Answer (score 11):

When you run `go build`, it will:

- Examine the package being built for `import` statements
- Examine each of the imported packages for `import` statements
- ... and so on, until it finds all transitive dependencies.
- For each package to be built, it then examines the [build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints), and builds the files that are not excluded. `*_test.go` files are excluded by default, `go test` explicitly includes them when building tests.

This means that:

- Test files won't be included in a non-test build unless you explicitly include them.
- Unreferenced packages won't be included at all.
- What's in `go.mod` is irrelevant to the build: it's used *only* for dependency management, *not* compilation.